# c# anonymous object, why only sometimes contains the field definitions?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

Why can I immediately access the anonymous object properties here:

```
    public object ComputeStats()
    {
        var obj = new
        {
            avg = 2,
            hi = 3,
            lo = 1
        };

        Console.WriteLine(obj.avg);

        return obj;
    }
```

But not here (compiler error 'object' does not contain definition for 'avg'):

```
    public void DisplayStats()
    {
        object stats = ComputeStats();
        Console.WriteLine("average: " + stats.avg);
    }
```

A workaround would be to declare stats as `dynamic`, but most would say to just create a class/type for this object. I'd rather use an anonymous object, but don't want to start using dynamic just for the convenience.

Comment: Your second example is not an anonymous object, it's simply an `object` with no defined properties.

Comment: because you declared your `stats` variable as type _object_, whereas you declared `obj` as _var_ (in other words; by using `var` you instructed the compiler to figure out the best type for _obj_, which is not `object` but `dynamic`)

Comment: This is why I hate var.

Comment: oops, ok. if i declare it as object it immediately doesnt work.

Comment: Use a tuple, not an anonymous type, for this usage case.

Comment: Your question is "why is the world this way?" but is that the question you really want answered? Are you looking for an explanation of how the language got to be this way, or are you looking for a better solution to your problem?

Comment: @EricLippert Yes I want to know why it is happening this way, as didn't seem to make sense. Part of a short decent answer may or may not include pointing at a better way of using or not using anonymous objects.

Comment: @elgonzo To be clear, `var` will infer the type, but it is not `dynamic`; with `var` the type is still resolved at compile time. E.g. `var x = SomeMethod();` resolves `x` to whatever `SomeMethod`'s _declared_ return type is.

Comment: @JoshuaWebb, absolutely true. I don't know why i was writing "dynamic" there. The `obj` variable will be of the anonymous type created there by `new { avg=2, ...}` and not dynamic.

Comment: The following "workaround" using C# 7 tuples comes most close to your intent: (Try in C# interactive): `(int avg, int hi, int lo) ComputeStats() => (2, 3, 1); var stats = ComputeStats(); WriteLine("average: " + stats.avg);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't specific to anonymous types. Everything inherits from `object` which means that you can implicitly cast anything as `object`.

Calling a method that returns an anonymous type and assigning it to a variable declared as `object` is the same as doing this:

```
object obj = new { avg = 2, hi = 3, lo = 1 };
```

`object` doesn't have properties like `avg`, `hi`, etc., so Visual Studio doesn't display them and if you type them they won't compile.

To illustrate using something other than an anonymous type:

```
var s = "Hello!";
object o = s;
```

There's only one `string`. Both `s` and `o` refer to a `string`. But `s` is cast as a `string` and `o` is cast as an `object`.

So you can do this:

```
var s = "Hello!";
object o = s;
var l = s.Length;
```

...but you can't do this:

```
var s = "Hello!";
object o = s;
var l = o.Length; // object doesn't have a Length property.
```

If you do this:

```
    var obj = new { avg = 2, hi = 3, lo = 1};
```

...using `var` means that the type is inferred. Whatever you're assigning to it, that's what the type is. In this case, behind the scenes, the compiler is actually creating a new type, so it behaves as if you had defined a type with those properties.

Anonymous types like this are handy for use within a method, but they're not meant for passing values between methods. For that either a class, struct, or tuple is better.

Comment: I think one last point is that the ComputeStats method in my example has a return type of "object", which really explains why I can't just do `var stats = ComputeStats()` to let the type be inferred from other methods.

Comment: That too. If a method returns something it has to specify the return type, which can't be anonymous.